# what does the following ssh command mean: `ssh login.com -L 6001:ld1.com:1521 -L 6002:ld2.com:1521`

Tags: ssh

Can somebody clarify what does the following command do?

`ssh login.com -L 6001:ld1.com:1521 -L 6002:ld2.com:1521`

I tried looking up man for it but it is still no clear.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It sets up a couple of ssh tunnel between login.com 
 one from port 6001 on login.com to ld1.com port 1521
 the other from port 6002 on login.com to ld2.com port 1521

This allows things to use the ports on ld1/2 specified as if they were the ports on login.com

This can be used for a variety of uses such as database ports or remote desktops